# Is it wise to ask for why a resume has been rejected?

Tags: job-search

Is this a common practice or even acceptable?

Comment: Have you tried searching this site for similar questions? There are many similar questions.

Comment: @enderland I did and did not find anything close to what I am looking for. Perhaps I did not use the right search terms?

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/10686/2322 http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17718/2322 http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/57496/2322 http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6018/2322

Answer (score 1):

It certainly can be, though if you are screened out in the very initial processes, you might have a difficult time getting anyone to respond to your queries.  Heck, sometimes it is impossible to get feedback even if you are a finalist.

Companies are very gun-shy about telling people why the did ***not*** get selected because they feel it would be like giving someone ammunition for a potential lawsuit. Even if they prevail, it's a nuisance to defend against some kind unfair treatment legal claim, so they instead will try to avoid saying anything.

It's not considered rude or out of place, though, so long as, when you ask, you ask in the spirit of trying to understand to make improvements for other opportunities in your job search, and not to argue with them about why they were wrong to do so.

Don't be surprised if, if they actually do respond, the only response you get is "you were an excellent candidate, but we felt another candidate was a better fit for the position."